# How to detect busy state in Twilio iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio, voip, twilio-click-to-call

I have successfully implement a APP to APP calling in iOS app using Twilio iOS SDK.

I have facing a problem in that Twilio SDK. I have explain with some step as below.

There are three user. User A, User B, User C

Step 1 : User A is calling to User B.

Step 2 : Now User C is calling to User A. User A is already talk with User B so what about User C. How can i identify busy state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this from your server-side app and relay the result to your iOS app.

The `Dial` verb includes an attribute named `action` which lets you specify a web application URL for Twilio to request when the call leg ends. That request includes a parameter named `DialCallStatus` which will tell you why the called ended. The `DialCallStatus` values include `busy` indicating Twilio received a busy signal when trying to connect to the called party.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-dial-call-status-values

Once your web application knows the `DialCallStatus`, you can relay it back to your iOS app and notify User C accordingly.